# Is it OK to rewrite a question you asked incorrectly?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I recently asked this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348009/unable-to-instantiate-class

I can see how people saw this as a bad question because what I thought was wrong I was way off. Because of what I thought was the problem, I did not provide the correct documentation.  I would however like to re-ask the same question worded better and provide the solution that I used. Though some moderators/users would feel like it was pretty obvious I am willing to bet someone out their has done it or will do it in the future.

The question was put on hold so I can't answer it. I have tried to put some clarity in comments. Is it appropriate to delete the question, re-ask the same question worded differently and answering my own question so the question and answer are permanently in Stack Overflow and searchable. I am asking first to make sure I don't get into a down vote reputation swarm.

Comment: @yellowantphil yeah that's a good point.  The only downside of that is that I need 4 more votes to get it reopened. How do people know that I just re-wrote everything and it needs to be re-evaluated.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess then I will gut the question and re-write it and make the notes in the comments.

Comment: The other advantage to a re-write is it clears out all the back and forth comments and the downvotes reset. Some people will just downvote because they see a lot of downvotes and just want to join the party.

Comment: If you actually edited the question such that it actually has enough code to reproduce the problem, then all you're doing is making the question become a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), as is already mentioned in the comments.  Spending a bunch of time editing the question just to make it a duplicate of a question already linked from that question isn't really a valuable use of your time, or the time of the reviewers that will need to reopen and then re-close the question.

Comment: I'd just delete the question before Meta effect kicks in and adds votes for not reading "NRE and Fix" question when you got NRE... Also in current state question contains way too much fluff (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+fluff )... As @Servy said the only thing you going to get out of editing is close as duplicate (and possibly more downvotes).

Comment: Grammar error. You should change `their` to `there` ;)

Comment: Side note: as it stand now question has 4 re-open votes and likely be showing up for many visitors of reopen queue slowly collecting downvotes due to missing MCVE. You may want to decide fate of the question sooner rather than waiting for Roomba to pick it up... Since you are not interested in deleting the question - edit it in shape with solid MCVE.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your specific case, there's no reason to do anything.  Your question is closed for lacking sufficient information to be answerable (more specifically, you're almost completely lacking a code sample of your problem, and you haven't adequately described the problem you are having with your code).

Normally, this is a problem that you'd want to fix, and it would be beneficial for you to include a minimal reproducible example and an accurate summary of the problem you're having, but if you included all of that information all you'd be doing is making your question a duplicate of the question already linked in the comments of your question (it being among of the most common duplicate targets).  Editing your question so that it no longer merits closure for one reason, but merits closure for another reason instead isn't really a productive use of anyone's time.  Anyone else with this problem can already find the canonical or any of the *thousands* of other duplicates out there.

In the more general case, outside of your specific example, yes, it's typically appropriate to improve your question when it is closed such that it no longer merits closure and can be reopened.  You'll want to make sure you're not changing *what the question is*, but rather are improving the question, it's presentation, it's clarity, etc. such that it is a better version *of the same question*.  You should only be asking a new question when the new question is fundamentally a new question, not an improved version of the existing question.

Comment: I think OP should just delete the question instead of waiting for Roomba to clean up (as the only reasonable action if they want to do something).

Comment: Thanks! Although I would humbly disagree with you that its a duplicate. At it's core yes technically its a null value problem. Sometimes people think about things differently. The 25 answers would have never solved my problem. In my assumption a class not instantiating was some problem that I was doing or possibly the way that class was declared was causing it to be uninstantiable. The real reason however was that I never thought it was making it inside the class so I never debugged that far. One variable in the class was returning null causing the whole thing to be null. I didn't know that.

Comment: @logixologist Your problem is *unquestionably* a duplicate.  It is literally no different than any of the other tens of thousands of null reference exception questions out there, and the canonical question would tell you *exactly* how to solve the problem.   Had you simply looked at the stack trace of the error it would tell you exactly the line of code causing problems, that you "never thought to look" at the line of code the error message is telling you caused the problem would be something you would have learned reading the duplicate.

Comment: I have to agree with OP here. People think differently and investigate problems differently even when the root cause is the same. If a different question, from a different perspective, leads to the same solution, it's still a valid question to keep in SO, as other people might think/proceed in a similar manner. Reinforcing how it is "unquestionably a duplicate" because the solution is the same and there are other ways of investigating doesn't change the fact that some people will still follow that particular train of thought that you seem to be judging as wrong.

Comment: @msb except that we have [3 thousands of those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/4660142?lq=1)

Comment: @msb You comment leads me to believe you haven't even read the question.  It has zero value.  All it says is that the OP has some code (not shown) that results in a Null Reference Exception.  That's it.  There is nothing of value there.  There's nothing in that question that is going to be more visible than any of the *thousands* of other duplicates, there's no different approach, there's no useful debugging information, nothing.